# Slow query in Mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, performance

I have the following slow query. cid and date are both index in each tables. There are 1M rows in each table. I need all columns in those three tables

```
 select * from 
    (SELECT * FROM `table1` where `cid` =? order by date desc limit 0, 10) as a 
        left join ( SELECT * FROM `table2` where `cid?` =?) as b on a.date=b.date? 
        left join (SELECT * FROM `table3` where `cid` =? ) as c on a.date=c.date? 
        order by date asc
```

Any suggestions how to improve the query?

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing or if you need all of the rows of the table, there's no right answer to your question.

Comment: @adamdehaven, I need all columns in those three tables.

Comment: Sorry, I thought "Slow query in Mysql" was a statement of fact, not a question :>

Comment: How slow is 'slow'? With 1M rows in each table it's not going to be instantaneous.

Comment: @DonLi - your question gives no insight into how many columns exist, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create seperate indexs on all Tables for the fields CID and date